# Auto Sorting Row As Data Is Entered

Tags: excel, vba

I have data sheet in which 'L' column heading is status where the following data is there:

```
ERROR
PENDING
DOC PEND
COMPLETED
```

As soon as I enter 'COMPLETED' then the row should be sorted out and go to top.

I want my sheet should show all completed row on top.

Please help me to do auto sort in this manner.

Comment: please stop "SHOUTING" in your question!

Comment: Use formula to another column, which will show sorted data as you finish typing.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the following into your worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
myBoolean = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not myBoolean Then
If Mid(Target.Address, 1, 2) = "$L" Then
On Error GoTo goodBye
If UCase(Target.Value) = "COMPLETED" Then
        Run moveRowToTop(Target.Row)
    End If
    myBoolean = False
End If
End If
goodBye:
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And then paste the following into a standard module.

```
Public myBoolean As Boolean

Function moveRowToTop(rowToChange As Long)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    myBoolean = True
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & rowToChange + 1 & ":L" & rowToChange + 1).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Rows(rowToChange + 1 & ":" & rowToChange + 1).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("L2").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Function
```

Try that and see if it does what you want.

Comment: Yes I want to add row up to row2 as I enter data n L column "completed"

Comment: Thank you very much @Solar Mike.